# Solving this optimal control problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory

The problem is:
$max \int_{-1}^1 (tx - u^2) dt$ where $\dot{x} = x + u^2, u(t) \in [0,1]$ for every $t \in [-1, 1]$

End points: $x(-1) = 0, x(1) = e^2 - e^{1 + \frac{1}{e}} $

I need to find an optimal pair x*, u* which maximizes the given problem.

Hamiltonian is $H(t, x, u, p) = tx - u^2 + px + pu^2$

So i started with finding u*(t) which is:

$
 u^*(t) =
  \begin{cases} 
      1 & \text{ if p(t) >= 1} \\
      0 & \text{ if p(t) < 1} \\
  \end{cases}
$

since u is maximized when $\frac{\partial H}{\partial u} = 0 = 2(p-1)u$

And from the mangasarian maximum principle $\dot{p} = -(t+p)$ which has general solution $p(t) = Ae^{-t} -t + 1$

I'm not sure what to do next. The hint given in the exercise is: Try with p(t) < 1 on an interval $(t_0, 1]$, where p is the adjoint function to the problem

I don't see how i can find this $t_0$ where p(t) < 1, when the constant A is unkown and has no condition required from the Maximum principle

UPDATE:
I think i'm on to something. Will post soon as i know more.

Comment: What's $\dot{x}$? Is the derivative with respect to $u$ or $t$?

Comment: With respect to t.

Comment: $\dot{x}$ is derivate of x (with respect to t). I've edited the OP a bit.